# detect the time from a secured place

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing mobile application using cordova ,
the mobile application should be on offline and online mode , i'm trying to get the time from a secure place when the user is offline (if i used device time the user may change it )

so I tried with :

1. trying to search for a plugin that can interact with the sim card and get the time from it .
2. searching for a way to detect if the user changed the time in the offline mode

but I don't find a solution

Comment: there is no way of doing this, but you can store the supposed time the user took place, and when it comes back online, before you sync the changes with the server, you check that the time was in range between the offline and online events, and if it isn't you discard the changes and warn the user

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some native code to do this, although it won't be much.  You could wrap it in your own plugin, or just modify one of the existing ones (the device plugin would make sense).  The device plugin on Android is a Java file and you could add a method in their that will call a JavaScript callback when a time change event is detected or just set a flag that a time change happened.

To actually detect the time change see the answer in this Stack Overflow answer:
[How to listen to change in time in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315840/how-to-listen-to-change-in-time-in-android)

In addition to the TIME_SET intent, you should listen for the TIMEZONE_CHANGE intent as well.

Comment: I tried to use the geolocation to get the timestamp and it works with me

  function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

        }
        var onSuccess = function (position) {
                 var date = new Date(position.timestamp * 1000);
            showAlert( 'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');
        };